# How can I view pending Cassandra repair tasks?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.2

I have a Cassandra 2.2.9 repair that has failed, and in this state the Cassandra metrics show about 70 repair tasks still pending. Cassandra should take care of retrying these failed tasks itself, but for whatever reason this time it has not.

The repairs take a long time, instead of running the whole repair again, can I see the chosen token ranges Cassandra uses for the repair so I can manually run the last few tasks instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I found is to search the logs at the time you started the repair - Cassandra spits out the ID and token range of each repair task it will attempt at the time you run the repair.

With Cassandra 2.2.9 I found grepping the logs for `new session: will sync` did the trick :)